# Braintree WebHook working Example in php

Tags: php, webhooks, braintree

Can Any one please provide me a working example of braintree webhook in php.I have used the below mentioned code to verify my link and it is working fine:

```
require_once 'braintree-php-2.22.0/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('jmvhd879pf68kfk8');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('cfywtwxy8bxmwtkn');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('ad3f3b6e9c8b8186c1204a0f533899da');

$bt_challenge_param = $_GET['bt_challenge'];
echo $response = Braintree_WebhookNotification::verify($bt_challenge_param);
```

But When i am writing the below mentioned code on the same page it is not writing to the file(there is no issue with text file path) even after payment success:

```
require_once 'braintree-php-2.22.0/lib/Braintree.php';

Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('jmvhd879pf68kfk8');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('cfywtwxy8bxmwtkn');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('ad3f3b6e9c8b8186c1204a0f533899da');

/*$bt_challenge_param = $_GET['bt_challenge'];
echo $response = Braintree_WebhookNotification::verify($bt_challenge_param);*/
$notification = Braintree_WebhookNotification::parse(
$_POST['bt_signature'],
$_POST['bt_payload']
);
$notification->kind == Braintree_WebhookNotification::SUB_MERCHANT_ACCOUNT_APPROVED;
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
$file = fopen("log.txt","w");
fwrite($file,$date."\r\n");
fwrite($file,$notification->merchantAccount->status."\r\n");
fwrite($file,$notification->merchantAccount->id."\r\n");
fwrite($file,$notification->merchantAccount->masterMerchantAccount->id."\r\n");
fwrite($file,$notification->merchantAccount->masterMerchantAccount->status."\r\n");
fwrite($file,"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n");
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need more info than you can easily get on Stack Overflow, please reach out to our [support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

We have a [webhook guide for each of our client libraries, including PHP](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php/guide/webhook_notifications).

Briefly:

```
if(
    isset($_POST["bt_signature"]) &&
    isset($_POST["bt_payload"])
) {
    $webhookNotification = Braintree_WebhookNotification::parse(
        $_POST["bt_signature"], $_POST["bt_payload"]
    );

    $message =
        "[Webhook Received " 
        . $webhookNotification->timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "] "
        . "Kind: " . $webhookNotification->kind . " | "
        . "Subscription: " . $webhookNotification->subscription->id . "\n";

    file_put_contents("/tmp/webhook.log", $message, FILE_APPEND);
}
```